# Walls logic in Pygame

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame, collision

I'm making a game with Pygame, and now I stuck on how to process collision between player and wall. This is 2D RPG with cells, where some of them are walls. You look on world from top, like in Pacman.

So, I know that i can get list of collisions by `pygame.spritecollide()` and it will return me list of objects that player collides. I can get "collide rectangle" by `player.rect.clip(wall.rect)`, but how I can get player back from the wall?

So, I had many ideas. The first was push player back in opposite direction, but if player goes, as example, both right and bottom directions and collide with vertical wall right of itself, player stucks, because it is needed to push only left, but not up.

The second idea was implement diagonally moving like one left and one bottom. But in this way we don't now, how move first: left or bottom, and order becomes the most important factor.

So, I don't know what algorithm I should use.

Comment: Is the game completely based on cells? As in every single object would be in a certain cell and the player can never be in a cell that an obstacle is in?

Comment: This is dynamic game, so, cell size is 64px, and player speed can be different, like (5, 5) etc. Cells is only location characteristc, player can walk where he wants. Hmm, like Minecraft. It has blocks, but player can move not only between blocks

Comment: Have you written any code? Seeing code would be helpful since this is a very broad question.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted code that process the collision. But i have this: GameObject class, Wall class(GameObject), Player class(GameObject), and every tick I can put anything in player.update() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the location of the centre of the cell and the location of the player you can calculate the x distance and the y distance from the wall at that point in time. Would it be possible at that point to take the absolute value of each distance and then take the largest value as the direction to push the player in.

e.g. The player collides with the right of the wall so the distance from the centre of the wall in the y direction should be less than the distance in x.
Therefore you know that the player collided with the left or the right of the wall and not the top, this means the push should be to the right or the left.

If the player's movement is stored as in the form [x, y] then knowing whether to push left or right isn't important since flipping the direction of movement in the x axis gives the correct result.

The push should therefore be in the x direction in this example
e.g. player.vel_x = -player.vel_x.
This would leave the movement in the y axis unchanged so hopefully wouldn't result in the problem you mentioned.

Does that help?

Comment: This looks like good algorithm, I'll think about it. But in this way, when should I calculate this? When I already collided with wall? And what will happen if I collide two or three walls at same time? And one else: speed of the player can be more than one block, so in next tick it might be not in the closest block

Comment: Yeah, the collision should occur and then the process above should take place. It might be necessary to adjust the position in the x axis or y axis if the object appears to be in the wall. If this happens then the process would be: update position, check for collisions, adjust movement speed, adjust the position in the same direction to ensure the object isn't displayed inside a wall for 1 frame then continue as normal

Comment: Thank you. I wiil try it tomorrow and check your answer

Comment: Colliding with three or more walls at the same time might not work with this if the speed of movement is too great. It might be possible to simply update the objects multiple times each frame at half the speed they're moving on screen to reduce the risk of such a problem but it might not be necessary.

Comment: It works! I can't stop wondering that is no questions about it in the Internet. Thank you!